# Best Cassandra data model for maintaining bounded lists per user

Tags: cassandra, cql, key-value-store

I have Kafka streams containing interactions of users with a website, so every event has a timestamp and information about the event. For each user I want to store the last K events in Cassandra (e.g. 100 events).

Our website is constantly experiencing bot / heavy users that is why we want to cap events, just to consider "normal" users.

I currently have the current data model in Cassandra:

```
 user_id, event_type, timestamp, event_blob
```

where

```
 <user_id, event_type> = partition key,   timestamp = clustering key
```

For now we write a new record in Cassandra as soon as a new event happens and later on we go and clean up "heavier" partitions (i.e. count of events > 100).
This doesn't happen in real time and until we don't clean up the heavy partitions we sometimes get bad latencies when reading.

Do you have any suggestions of a better table design for such case? 
Is there a way to tell Cassandra to store only at most K elements for partition and expire the old ones in a FIFO way? Or is there a better table design that I can opt for?

Comment: Did you try to use LIMIT for you read queries? If you need just 100 latest records it can be an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have any suggestions of a better table design for such case?

When data modeling for scenarios like this, I recommend a pattern that makes use of three things:

- Default TTL set on the table.
- Clustering on a time component in descending order.
- Adjust query to use a range on the timestamp, never querying data past the TTL.

**TTL:**

> later on we go and clean up "heavier" partitions

How long (on average) before the cleanup happens?  One thing I would do, is to use a TTL on that table set to somewhere around the maximum amount of time before your team usually has to clean them up.

**Clustering Key, Descending Order:**

So your PRIMARY KEY definition looks like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((user_id,event_type),timestamp)
```

Make sure that you're also clustering in a descending order on timestamp.

```
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC)
```

This is important to use in conjunction with your TTL.  Here, your tombstones are on the "bottom" of the partition (when sorting on `timestamp` descinding) and the recent data (the data you care about) is at the "top" of the partition.

**Range Query:**

Finally, make sure your query has a range component on the `timestamp`.

For example: if today is the 11th, and my TTL is 5 days, I can then query the last 4 days of data without pulling back tombstones:

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE user_id = 11111 AND event_type = 'B'
AND timestamp > '2020-03-07 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Thanks! The clustering key part especially helped a lot! Unfortunately my TTL is higher (we want to keep the last 2 months events per user, capped at 2k at most) and the partition fills up quickly. So I am thinking about a cron job for deletions plus a realtime counter of the partitions to avoid writes

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your existing implementation is that deletes create tombstones which eventually cause latencies in the read. Creating too many tombstones is not recommended.

FIFO implementation based on count (number of rows per partition) is not possible. The better approach for your use case is not to delete records in the same table. Use Spark to migrate the table into a new temp table and remove the extra records in the migration process. Something like:

1) Create a new table

2) Using Spark , read from the orignal table , migrate all required records (filter extra records) and write to new temp table.

3) Truncate the orignal table. Note that truncate operation do not create Tombstones.

4) Migrate everything from the temp table back to orignal table using Spark.

5) Truncate the temp table.

You can do this in maintenance window of your application ( something like once in a month) until then you can restrict reads with Limit 100 per partition.